# Why is my edit attributed to another user?

Tags: support, editing, suggested-edits

I recently tried to edit [a question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/144677/91891) and someone else beat me to the punch. I reviewed their edit and felt like my edit would further improve their edit, so I resubmitted my edit. After resubmitting my edit I got the standard message that my edit would have to be reviewed. A minute or so later I refreshed the screen and noticed the "edit must be reviewed" message was gone but someone else was credited with the edit. I thought they must have improved my edit, so I looked at the edit history and didn't see my name.

[image: edit history]

Either this other user re-edited their edit to match my edit or my edit somehow is under another user's name. To be clear I don't feel the need to have my name on the edit or get the 2 rep from the edit. I just want to understand what happened because it looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following happend:

1. We both were editing at the same time, but you submitted your edit first. So when I submitted mine it overwrote yours.
2. I saw what had happend, and thought your edit was much better than mine. So I figured I better restore it.
3. While I was resubmitting your edit, you did the same. And again I ended up overwriting your edit.

I realize I ended up both robbing you off the rep gain from editing, as well as taking credit for your work. Sorry about that. Would be happy for any pointers on how to deal with similar situations in the future.

Comment: No sweat. I'm just glad we solved the mystery. It was just a fluke thing that we both happened to be editing the same question and both working fast. As long as the OP benefits I consider this mission accomplished.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough rep to be able to see this, but [sometimes this happens](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199909/133872) because the other user used "improve edit" but unchecked "suggested edit was helpful".

The section "How can I check on my own suggested edits?" on [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) describes how to get a link to the suggested edit page, which will provide more information on this.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll look for that check box when I review edits in the future.

Comment: Is that checkbox still in use? On Stack Overflow it is replaced by the buttons "Improve Edit" and "Reject and Edit".

Comment: @S.L.Barth Yeah, that is how it works here as well (if my memory serves me right).